# Refreshing only parts of the form in F#

Tags: winforms, f#, refresh

How do i refresh only some parts of a form? I currently update the form every 100 milliseconds. However, it updates everything on the screen and not just the altering objects. Which means everything that is static and doesnt change in values just stand there blinking at every update. I would like only the moving objects to be rendered. How do you achieve this in F#? Should i update somehow differently than updating the Form?

```
let win = new Form();
win.Refresh()
```

Between that i have a lot of code that i cannot share due to restrictions. Is it possible to refresh only certain things in the window somehow?

Thanks in advance, Anders.

Comment: [`Control.Invalidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bk29t0f.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you'd just change the values on the form for the things that need updating.  This should automatically redraw those, without refreshing the form itself.

However, if you're doing custom drawing, or other things that would require an explicit invalidation, you can call [`Control.Invalidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to invalidate a control.  If you need to guarantee that it's redrawn synchronously, after calling `Invalidate`, you can call [`Update`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update(v=vs.110).aspx).